ObjectBox Sync questions
I am very close to finishing my OBX Sync project, but i need some answers to finish it.

How can i restart sync? (for example the server IP address changes in the background, ). Currently i have to restart the whole app, to restart sync.
How can i determine, when OBX finished sync on login? I will control the UI, and let show / control the user that all data are up-to-date / sync in progress. For example: user A went on vacation, and in the meantime his permissions are revoked. Since the user's device was not connected to the server, these changes were not synced locally. When the user logs in again, during the synchronization the user's data may be synchronized later than when he logged in, so he can log in even if he no longer exists on the server.
Thanks


To restart a SyncClient after a configuration change, please close it and create a new instance. Assuming you have an existing SyncClient instance called syncClient, it should look something like this:
syncClient.close();  // Important to close first...
syncClient = Sync.client( /* new config here */ );
syncClient.start()

For the second question, I think there are some listeners mentioned in the docs:

loginEvents: such as logged-in, credentials-rejected
completionEvents: observe when synchronization has completed
connectionEvents: observe connection events

Hope that helps.

completitionEvent would be good, but if nothing to synced, this event will not fired  so if i wait on start the app for this event to run i can wait until doomsday...
ComletitionEvent.NothingToSync will be fine in this case...

another idea is the list of tables to sync on sync start

"completitionEvent would be good, but if nothing to synced, this event will not fired" --> did you try this?

I checked and it runs, but unfortunately it ALWAYS runs. So it doesn't run at the end of the entire synchronization process, but after each data sync. So, unfortunately, it cannot be used to determine whether the entire process has been completed, or whether it has only finished with the currently synchronized data. I might be doing something wrong, but unfortunately there is no more information about this in the documentation. Maybe I could get a Flutter/Dart example?

Note that you should get a completitionEvent every time the client is up-to-date with the server. Thus, if newer operations come in, you'll get this event. The sync is complete because there are no more outstanding operations on the server side.

The event itself is the information, there's no additional data that needs to be given to users. Please state what you want to do, and why the current APIs do not give the functionality.

Understand, but how? i do completionEvents.listen((event) {}, but "event" is void...
connectionEvents.listen((SyncConnectionEvent event) {} there is "event" a type, so i can handle different types of events. But in this case, i only get if it finished. If at start are 1000 products to sync, i get this event 1000x... And what if only 1 product to sync? Or 13? how do i know how many?

I want control the UI on startup. If sync in progress, the app have to wait (Sync in progress screen). If done, the user can log-in.

"If at start are 1000 products to sync, i get this event 1000x." This is unexpected and it sounds like you are adding the products after the app started? If these 1000 products already exist on the server when your client starts syncing, you should only get it once, after all 1000 products were received.

can i share and debug messages anywhere with you, to show what my problem is?

Code for start sync is:
startSync(BuildContext context) async {
  bool available = Sync.isAvailable();
  syncServerIP = '';

  if (available) {
    syncClient = Sync.client(objectBox!.store, 'ws://$syncServerIP', SyncCredentials.none());
    syncClient!.start();
    syncClient!.requestUpdates(subscribeForFuturePushes: true);
    final loginsubscription = syncClient!.loginEvents.listen((SyncLoginEvent event) {
      print('Login event: $event');
    });
    final changeSubscription = syncClient!.changeEvents.listen((List<SyncChange> event) => event.forEach((change) {
      debugPrint('${change.entity} '
              'puts=${change.puts} removals=${change.removals}');
    })).onDone(() {
      print('Sync done');
    });
    final connectionSubscription = syncClient!.connectionEvents.listen((SyncConnectionEvent event) {
      switch (event) {
        case SyncConnectionEvent.connected:
          print('Connected to Sync Server');
          syncClient!.requestUpdates(subscribeForFuturePushes: true);
          break;
        case SyncConnectionEvent.disconnected:
          print('Disconnected from Sync Server');
          break;
      }
    });
    final completionSubscription = syncClient!.completionEvents.listen((event) {
      print('Sync event fired');
    });
  } else {
    print('Sync not available');
  }
}

the debug messages on start the app after startSync() started:
I/flutter ( 6484): ProductGroup puts=[] removals=[]
I/flutter ( 6484): Sync event fired
I/flutter ( 6484): Product puts=[] removals=[]
I/flutter ( 6484): Sync event fired
I/flutter ( 6484): TableMapElement puts=[46, 49, 51, 52, 55, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 85, 94, 97] removals=[]
I/flutter ( 6484): TableMap puts=[] removals=[]
I/flutter ( 6484): Sync event fired
I/flutter ( 6484): TableMapElement puts=[] removals=[46, 49, 51, 52, 55, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 85, 94, 97]
I/flutter ( 6484): Sync event fired
I/flutter ( 6484): TableGUID puts=[] removals=[]
I/flutter ( 6484): Sync event fired
I/flutter ( 6484): TableGUID puts=[82] removals=[]
I/flutter ( 6484): Sync event fired
I/flutter ( 6484): TableGUID puts=[83] removals=[]
I/flutter ( 6484): Sync event fired
I/flutter ( 6484): TableGUID puts=[84] removals=[]
I/flutter ( 6484): Sync event fired
I/flutter ( 6484): TableGUID puts=[85] removals=[]
I/flutter ( 6484): Sync event fired
I/flutter ( 6484): TableGUID puts=[86] removals=[]
I/flutter ( 6484): Sync event fired
I/flutter ( 6484): TableGUID puts=[87] removals=[]
I/flutter ( 6484): Sync event fired
I/flutter ( 6484): TableGUID puts=[88] removals=[]
I/flutter ( 6484): Sync event fired
I/flutter ( 6484): TableGUID puts=[89] removals=[]
I/flutter ( 6484): Sync event fired
I/flutter ( 6484): TableGUID puts=[90] removals=[]
I/flutter ( 6484): Sync event fired
I/flutter ( 6484): TableGUID puts=[91] removals=[]
I/flutter ( 6484): Sync event fired
I/flutter ( 6484): ProductGroup puts=[1] removals=[]
I/flutter ( 6484): Sync event fired
I/flutter ( 6484): ProductGroup puts=[2] removals=[]
I/flutter ( 6484): Sync event fired
I/flutter ( 6484): ProductGroup puts=[3] removals=[]
I/flutter ( 6484): Sync event fired
I/flutter ( 6484): ProductGroup puts=[4] removals=[]
I/flutter ( 6484): Sync event fired
I/flutter ( 6484): ProductGroup puts=[6] removals=[]
I/flutter ( 6484): Sync event fired
I/flutter ( 6484): ProductGroup puts=[7] removals=[]
I/flutter ( 6484): Sync event fired
I/flutter ( 6484): ProductGroup puts=[9] removals=[]
I/flutter ( 6484): Sync event fired
I/flutter ( 6484): ProductGroup puts=[10] removals=[]
I/flutter ( 6484): Sync event fired
I/flutter ( 6484): ProductGroup puts=[12] removals=[]
I/flutter ( 6484): Sync event fired
I/flutter ( 6484): ProductGroup puts=[13] removals=[]
I/flutter ( 6484): Sync event fired
I/flutter ( 6484): ProductGroup puts=[14] removals=[]
I/flutter ( 6484): Sync event fired
I/flutter ( 6484): ProductGroup puts=[15] removals=[]
I/flutter ( 6484): Sync event fired
I/flutter ( 6484): ProductGroup puts=[16] removals=[]
I/flutter ( 6484): Sync event fired
I/flutter ( 6484): ProductGroup puts=[17] removals=[]
I/flutter ( 6484): Sync event fired
...
and so on...

As you can see, the event runs after each data sync (After each piece of data, you see "Sync event fired", which, if you look at the code, is in the completionEvent.listen procedure.
In this case, how can i be sure, if sync is finished, or still running?
